# How to Pass args without affecting "self"

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I've been working with this code for a days now.

I cant make it work, my goal is to pass an arguments from a function from a different CLASS to another function in a different CLASS without affecting the '**self**'

Please see sample code.

PY CODE:

```
`    
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button



#Custom Button
class PassdataButton(Button):
    def on_release(self):
        ThisScreen.getters(datas=['5','3'])

class ThisScreen(Screen):
    def getters(self,datas):
        self.ids.gettersBox.text = f"There is {datas[0]} Apple's and {datas[0]} Banana's"

class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv_file = Builder.load_file('getData.kv')

class projectApps(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv_file

if __name__ == "__main__":
    projectApps().run()
`
```

KV CODE:

```
SM:
    ThisScreen:
        name: 'ThisScreen'


<ThisScreen>:

    canvas.before:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            source: 'im-502378444.jpg'

    BoxLayout:
        padding: 10
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput:
            id: gettersBox

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: .3
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Button:
                text: 'GetterButton'
                on_release: root.getters(datas = 'this data is from GetterButton')

            #CustomButton    
            PassdataButton:
                text: "Apple's & Banana's"
```

Everytime I run the code and click the Custom Button I created, it's getting me an error

```
     ThisScreen.getters(datas=['5','3'])
 TypeError: getters() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

When I add a value for the missing positional argument for self like `ThisScreen.getters(self=True, datas=['5','3'])` its giving me different error and I cant access/call anymore other elements under the the getters() function.

```
     self.ids.gettersBox.text = f"There is {datas[0]} Apple's and {datas[0]} Banana's"
 AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'ids'
```

Hope you can help me with this simple code.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

**1.** You can pass it direct from your kv file. Since you're already on the `ThisScreen` screen, you can just delete your `on_relase` method in python and call the function inside `.kv` from root like this:

```
PassdataButton:
    text: "Apple's & Banana's"
    on_release: root.getters(datas=['5', '3'])
```

**2.** Or if you want to use python for this, you will have to get your running app, the screen manager, then jump to the screen with the desired function, and only there you can call your getter:

```py
class PassdataButton(Button):
    def on_release(self):
        App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('ThisScreen').getters(datas=['5', '3'])
# App -> App instance
# get_running_app() -> current running
# root -> Screen Manager
# get_screen('ThisScreen') -> Desired screen
```

Comment: DEEP!!! 

Option 2 was the sweetest, I can apply it to other object like touches or RV..
really appreciate the answer.

This is the thing that im looking in Kivy documentation, how to view the hierarchical view of the object/widget just like this ---->>

'App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('ThisScreen').getters'

can you point me where I can find this documentation? thanks a lot!

Comment: You can read more about it on the [App class documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html) and in the [Screen Manager (your root) documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html?highlight=screen%20manager#module-kivy.uix.screenmanager)